# Swift: Associate a tuple to a enum

Tags: ios, swift, rawrepresentable

Is there a way to associate a tuple to a enum?

For example:

```
typealias MyTuple = (Int, String)

enum A: MyTuple {
   case .Foo = (1, "Bazz")
}
```

I get the error 'A does not conform RawRepresentable'

Comment: From the Swift reference: *"Raw values can be strings, characters, or any of the integer or floating-point number types. ..."*

Comment: Although asking about associating a tuple to an enum, another approach to solving the underlying problem the OP is trying to solve could be to use nested enums.